# How can I optimize my BitmapTextureAtlas in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

Currently I have 4 different images that I am loading into 4 seperate BitmapTextureAtlas's. 
What I would like to do is load 4 different images inside 1 BitMapTextureAtlas to try and optimize speed. I have edited the code to what I believe should have made it work however when this (Live wallpaper) loads the texture, the screen is just white. Here is what I have done so far:

**onLoadResources()**

Original BitmapTextureAtlas:

```
this.StarsAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);   
this.SpaceAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
this.CloudsAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
this.SunetAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I have condensed to:

```
this.skyAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 4096, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
```

Original Texture Regions:

```
    this.LayerStars = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory 
            .createFromAsset(this.StarsAtlas, this,
                    "stars.jpg", 0, 0); //568x518
    this.LayerSpace = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.SpaceAtlas, this,
                    "space.jpg", 0, 0); //500x800
    this.LayerClouds = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.CloudsAtlas, this,
                    "clouds.jpg", 0, 0); //600x478
    this.LayerSunset = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.SunsetAtlas, this,
                    "sunset.jpg", 0, 0); //997x460
```

I have changed to:

```
    this.LayerStars = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.skyAtlas, this,
                    "stars.jpg", 0, 0); //568x518
    this.LayerSpace = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.skyAtlas, this,
                    "space.jpg", 0, 518); //500x800
    this.LayerClouds = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.skyAtlas, this,
                    "clouds.jpg", 0, 1318); //600x478
    this.LayerSunset = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.skyAtlas, this,
                    "sunset.jpg", 0, 1796); //997x460
```

Loading the texture:

```
this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
            this.skyAtlas);
```

...Later on in the **onLoadScene()**
This stays the same:

```
    Sprite starSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, 568, 518, this.LayerStars);
    Sprite cloudSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, 600, 478, this.LayerClouds);
    Sprite spaceSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, 500, 800, this.LayerSpace);
    Sprite sunsetSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, 997, 460, this.LayerSunset);
```

Any idea what could be causing the white screen?
On a side note, it loaded fine when I had 4 different images in 4 separate BitmapTextureAtlas's.

Comment: in the Original BitmapTextureAtlas you have a typo in this.SunetAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can see is that you are using different texture options. Have you tried TextureOptions.DEFAULT instead of TextureOptions.BILINEAR? Theturtleboy on the AndEngine forums had some problems with JPEGs using the same settings. See http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/jpeg-support-t26.html

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have tried every TextureOption as well as converting the jpges to pngs but still no luck.

Comment: Then maybe you've hit the TextureAtlas size limitations (which may differ across various devices). Try 2048x2048 instead.

Comment: Interesting, that seemed to fix it. I used only 2 images with a 1024x2048 BitmapTextureAtlas. It seems 4096 is too much. At least now I know I can condense at least 2 images into 1 Atlas. Thanks for the help

Comment: And using a 2048x2048 I was able to get all 4 on there

Comment: You can put many, many more images in one Atlas, I suggest you take a look at BlackPawnTextureBuilder which is a part of AndEngine. It does the magic of efficiently placing many images into the Atlas without you having to specify the coordinates.